# no module named disco.core

Tags: python, disco

I've been following the tutorial here: http://discoproject.org/doc/disco/start/install.html

and have been succesful up to the point where I run the script.  I get the error:

```
no module named disco.core
```

I have installed disco according to the instructions above, but this doesn't seem to have installed the python library.

I have tried installing it using conda, pip, and easy_install without any luck..

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `make install` and it should install disco libs in standard location (site-packages or dist-packages).

Comment: I did that, but I think I see the problem now.  I am running anaconda and this installed disco under my regular mac python install.  Any way to force this to the correct place?

Comment: find it and add to env variable PYTHONPATH or in code with `sys.path.append('/path/to/discolib')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for only the installation of the library into a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv some_venv_here && source some_venv_here/lib/activate
git clone https://github.com/discoproject/disco.git
cd disco/lib
python setup.py install
```